How to install slim syntax highlighting in Neovim?
How can I install syntax highlighting for .slim?
I have Neovim and lazy.nvim package manager, also I have TreeSitter

vim-slim is an Vim plugin that adds Vim support for slim template format:
To configure [lazy.nvim] to use slim you have to edit ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua and add the slim url to the list returned:
return {
 -- your existing list of plugin: >>
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    dependencies = { "hrsh7th/cmp-emoji" },
    ---@param opts cmp.ConfigSchema
    opts = function(_, opts)
      local cmp = require("cmp")
      opts.sources = cmp.config.sources(vim.list_extend(opts.sources, { { name = "emoji" } }))
    end,
  },
 -- <<
  {
    "slim-template/vim-slim"
  },
}


It was this, because I have every plugin in its own file
return { 
  "slim-template/vim-slim"
}


@D.BenKnoble, you are an incredible safety net and the best moderator ever!
